# How to count and extract questions in a text, in R?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

I have found multiple answers about counting numbers of sentences, but how to extract specifically questions out of text, in R?

Comment: If you assume that every question ends in a question mark, you could just count the number of question marks.

Comment: I want to not only count but also extract the questions.

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is this. It uses `str_split`from the package `stringr` as well as `grep`from `base R`:

Data:

```
example <- "This is a question? not a question. This is also a question?"
```

Solution:

```
library(stringr)
grep("\\?$", unlist(str_split(example, "(?<=\\?|\\.|!)\\s")), value = T)
```

Here, we first `str_split` the string into a list of sentences, using positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) to match sentence punctuation characters and the whitespace character `\\s` following the sentence boundaries as split points, then `unlist` the list and finally match those sentences that end (`$`) in a question mark:

Result:

```
[1] "This is a question?"      "This is also a question?"
```

To count the number of questions you can simply wrap the function `length` around the whole `grep` expression.

Alternatively, you can use `str_extract_all` like this:

```
str_extract_all(example, "(?<=^|\\?|\\.|!| )\\w[a-zA-Z ]+\\?")
[[1]]
[1] "This is a question?"      "This is also a question?"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you always expect a question to end in a question mark, you could try something like the following.

Make some example data.

```
example <- "This is a question? not a question. This is also a question?"
```

Count the questions.

```
stringr::str_count(example, "\\?")
# [1] 2
```

Extract the questions. You may need to modify the regex more to fit your data.

```
stringr::str_match_all(example, "(?<=\\s|^)([\\w\\s\\d\\(\\)\\[\\];:,]+\\?)")[[1]][,2]
# [1] "This is a question?"      "This is also a question?"
```